# remove vertical gaps between divs and put in a sequence

Tags: html, css

It is now like this:

[image: in order]

I want like this:

[image: order]

my css:

```
.maindiv{
    width:410px;
}
.innerdiv{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/021eqc92/)

this is an [example page](http://uz.ucom.my/)

Comment: there is no related answer there to my question @Ormoz

Comment: You can use two main div side by side and have these inner div inside that

Comment: @Elyor short answer: avoid `whitespace` between `inline-block` elements

Comment: I will try that, thanks

Comment: (can't post as answer since it's marked as duplicate), you can use :nth-child  `.innerdiv:nth-child(odd){
    float: left;
}`

`.innerdiv:nth-child(even){
    float: right;
} ` [JSFIDDLE-DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/021eqc92/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy implementation ,just use display:flex on main div and make two columns div to wrap inner div

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="innerdiv">
           <img style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="innerdiv">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 120px;"/>
         </div>      
         <div class="innerdiv">
             <img style="width: 100%; height: 220px;"/>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-1">
        <div class="innerdiv">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 260px;"/>
         </div>
         <div class="innerdiv">
              <img style="width: 100%; height: 180px;"/>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.maindiv {
width: 410px;
display: flex;
}
```

**Result**

[image]